# Can not use csvsimple and have accent characters at the same time

Tags: sectioning, accents, csvsimple

When parsing in XeLaTeX the template available in [SIGCHI](http://www.sigchi.org/publications/chipubform/sigchi-papers-latex-template/view) with the package [`csvsimple`](http://texblog.org/tag/csvsimple/) and "fontspec" (to include special UTF8 accent characters), I'm able to see "áéíóú" in the body of the document but not in the titles of the sections or in references.

For instance: "Detección" is displayed as "Deteccin". Is there a way to conserve `csvsimple` and have the accented characters at the same time?

PD: I also used `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with pdflatex but that is not compatible with `csvsimple`.

Adding the MWE that works in XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{sigchi}
\usepackage{balance}  % to better equalize the last page
\usepackage{graphics} % for EPS, load graphicx instead
\usepackage{times}    % comment if you want LaTeX's default font
\usepackage{url}      % llt: nicely formatted URLs
\makeatletter
\def\url@leostyle{%
  \@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\sf}}{\def\UrlFont{\small\bf\ttfamily}}}
\makeatother
\urlstyle{leo}
\def\pprw{8.5in}
\def\pprh{11in}
\special{papersize=\pprw,\pprh}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{\pprw}
\setlength{\paperheight}{\pprh}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\pprw}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\pprh}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
pdftitle={SIGCHI Conference Proceedings Format},
pdfauthor={LaTeX},
pdfkeywords={SIGCHI, proceedings, archival format},
bookmarksnumbered,
pdfstartview={FitH},
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
breaklinks=true,
}
\newcommand\tabhead[1]{\small\textbf{#1}}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\section{Acústica}
Acústica
\end{document}
```

The result is: 
La Acstica (as the section title, notice that there is no ú)
Acústica (in the body)

Comment: Could you, please, provide a compilable MWE to help us to understand the problem? Currently, I cannot see how `csvsimple` interferes with accents in section titles.

Comment: `csvsimple` is compatible with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. There could be problems with files containing the UTF-8 BOM. This can be easily solved by http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209853/ignore-utf-8-bom-with-csvsimple/209871#209871

Comment: I added the MWE, thanks for any help! I tried also using \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FEFF}{}, but later got "Unicode char \u8:χ not set up for use with LaTeX"

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `csvsimple` as far as I can see. The class sigchi seems to use a font for the sections which does not contain the accents (?)...

Comment: Nice, thanks Thomas! Is this the line you are referring to? \@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\sf}}{\def\UrlFont{\small\bf\ttfamily}}}

Comment: No. I just saw that the font of the section was different when I viewed the compiled example. I don't know what `sigchi` actually does.

Comment: Ok, you are reffering to this: \documentclass[spanish]{sigchi}. I read from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74262/orphans-when-using-the-sigchi-latex-style that the SIGCHI class is really old (more than 20 years and was written for LaTeX 2.09), I guess there is no quick fix right?

Comment: Ok, I located the problem. When using \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and PdfTeX I have the accent symbols in the title (one reference has a non utf-8 character in jabref, so I removed it). How ever I can not use PdfTeX and csvsimple although I'm importing the package (\usepackage{csvsimple}). I'm getting an "! Undefined control sequence." Some ideas?? Thanks!

Comment: It makes little sense using XeLaTeX along with `\usepackage{times}`. Use `pdflatex` (and `\usepackage{mathptmx}`), with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I located the problem: I had some special characters in jabref and in the CSV file. I was loading a .bib file with some Chinese non utf-8 characters and in the CSV I was using 'ó' in the headers. After removing them, the problems were solved.

This combination worked for me:

- SIGCHI template
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{csvsimple}
- PdfTeX